Remove duplicate rows from LEFT JOIN with SELF JOIN
How to create a join that has all product_features with all feature_text rows

that joins a specific text for a feature if available
or else joins the general text for that feature?

The join must not have duplicated rows and must pivot two languages into two different columns. The join should be as efficient / as fast as possible.
The relation between product_features and  feature_text is

Products can have a specific text for a feature code (B12XBE for DSP)
or just a general text for a feature code (DSP, XAB for UTB2EF & X9Y8Z7)


The result of the query should be this



Year
product
feature
prod_group
text_de
text_en




2024
B12XBE
DSP
B1
Anzeige 2,5
Display 1"


2024
B12XBE
B70
B1
NULL
B1 hard...


2024
UTB2EF
U04
UT
NULL
UT diam...


2024
UTB2EF
DSP
NULL
Anzeige
Display


2024
X9Y8Z7
DSP
NULL
Anzeige
Display


2024
X9Y8Z7
XAB
X9
13mm for ...
13mm für ..



If a specified text is available (B1 DSP) use this text Display 1" otherwise use the non-specific (DSP) text Display
My query below produces false matches (gist, sqlime.org demo):

See 2nd row 2024    B12XBE  A1C B1  B1 hardened steal   UT gehärteter Stahl is wrong. The texts should always start with UT.
Row 4,5,7 and 9 are also incorrect.


Sample:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_features;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feature_text;
CREATE TABLE product_features (
    year INTEGER, -- (4)
    product TEXT, -- (6)
    feature TEXT -- (3)
);
CREATE TABLE feature_text (
    year INTEGER, -- (4)
    product_group TEXT,
     -- (2) usually matches the first two digits of product
     -- but is sometimes empty / NULL or blank ' '
    feature TEXT, -- (3)
    language INTEGER, -- (2)
    description1 TEXT -- up to 40
);

INSERT INTO product_features (year, product, feature) VALUES
    (2024, 'B12XBE', 'A1C'), (2024, 'B12XBE', '7B0'),
    (2024, 'B12XBE', 'DUL'), (2024, 'UTB2EF', 'A1C'),
    (2024, 'UTB2EF', '7B0'), (2024, 'UTB2EF', 'DUL'),
    (2024, 'X9Y8Z7', 'DUH'), (2024, 'X9Y8Z7', '7B0');

INSERT INTO feature_text
 (year, product_group, feature, language, description1)
VALUES
  (2024, 'B1', 'A1C', 1, 'B1 hardened steel'),
  (2024, 'B1', '7B0', 1, 'B1 diamond tip'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'DSP', 1, 'display 1 inch'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'DSP', 1, 'Anzeige 1,5 cm'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'A1C', 1, 'UT hardened steel'),
  (2024, 'UT', '7B0', 1, 'UT diamond tip'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'DSP', 1, 'display 1,5 inch'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'DSP', 1, 'Anzeige 2,25 cm'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUL', 1, '10mm for light duty'),
  (2024, 'X9', '7B0', 1, 'X9 diamond tip'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUH', 1, '13mm for heavy duty'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'A1C', 2, 'B1 gehärteter Stahl'),
  (2024, 'B1', '7B0', 2, 'B1 Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'A1C', 2, 'UT gehärteter Stahl'),
  (2024, 'UT', '7B0', 2, 'UT Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUL', 2, '10mm für leichte Aufgaben'),
  (2024, 'X9', '7B0', 2, 'X9 Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUH', 2, '13mm für schwere Aufgaben'),
  (2024, NULL, 'DSP', 1, 'display'),
  (2024, NULL, 'DSP', 1, 'Anzeige');

My approach:
WITH prft_en as (
SELECT
pf.year, pf.product, pf.feature,
COALESCE(ft1.product_group, ft2.product_group) AS product_group,
COALESCE(ft1.description1, ft2.description1) AS feature_text_en,
COALESCE(ft1.language, ft2.language) AS language_en
  FROM product_features pf
    LEFT JOIN feature_text  ft1
                 ON pf.year = ft1.year
                 AND pf.feature = ft1.feature
                 AND substr(pf.product, 1,2) = ft1.product_group
    LEFT JOIN feature_text ft2
                 ON pf.year = ft2.year
                 AND pf.feature = ft2.feature
                 AND ft2.product_group is ' ' OR ft2.product_group is NULL
WHERE ft1.language = 1 OR ft2.language = 1
), prft_de AS (
SELECT
pf.year, pf.product, pf.feature,
COALESCE(ft1.product_group, ft2.product_group) AS product_group,
COALESCE(ft1.description1, ft2.description1) AS feature_text_de,
COALESCE(ft1.language, ft2.language) AS language_de
  FROM product_features pf
    LEFT JOIN feature_text  ft1
                 ON pf.year = ft1.year
                 AND pf.feature = ft1.feature
                 AND substr(pf.product, 1,2) = ft1.product_group
    LEFT JOIN feature_text ft2
                 ON pf.year = ft2.year
                 AND pf.feature = ft2.feature
                 AND ft2.product_group is ' ' OR ft2.product_group is NULL
WHERE ft1.language = 2 OR ft2.language = 2
)

Query for the CTEs:
SELECT prft_en.year, prft_en.product,
       prft_en.feature, prft_en.product_group,
       prft_en.feature_text_en, prft_de.feature_text_de
FROM prft_en
     LEFT JOIN prft_de
     ON prft_en.year = prft_de.year
     AND prft_en.feature = prft_de.feature
     AND SUBSTR(prft_en.product, 1,2) = prft_en.product_group


There are no duplicate rows in the output you show, each row differs in at least one column, can you more clearly describe what you mean? Also please add what output you want. And please don't add images of text (or tables) add the text (table) directly .

I am still trying to figure which query runs faster. For a demo with more records @AlexU query is faster but the results are so hugely different that maybe i did make a mistake https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/341990/

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking
a question? [mre] [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments & delete & flag obsolete comments.

There should be no images & way less code.

Please EITHER ask about bad code with the obligatory [mre] & why you
think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it
doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative
documentation, OR ask about your overall goal giving working parts you
can do & ideally a [mre]--then bad code does not belong. But please ask about the former 1st because
misconceptions will get in the way of understanding the latter. And
bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do.

A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest
representative example input as code; desired & actual output
(including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear
specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is
code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.
(Debugging fundamental.) (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Hello @philipxy to my understanding i provide  a reproducible example
at https://sqlime.org/#deta:4qpfg9d2lbpp and the indented goal is in the table i added. I will update the columns text_de, text_en to include some text to better convey the intent.

Your comment is not helpful. 1. A MRE needs to be in a post. 2. Please act per my comments.

I suppose all you need is the LEFT join by complex condition. Like this:
select 
    product_features.year,
    product_features.product,
    product_features.feature,
    substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) AS product_group,
    text_en.description1 AS en,
    text_de.description1 AS de
FROM product_features
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_en
ON text_en.year = product_features.year
AND text_en.feature = product_features.feature
AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_en.product_group OR text_en.product_group IS NULL OR TRIM(text_en.product_group) = '')
AND text_en.language = 1
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_de
ON text_de.year = product_features.year
AND text_de.feature = product_features.feature
AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_de.product_group OR text_de.product_group IS NULL OR TRIM(text_de.product_group) = '')
AND text_de.language = 2

Note that you will get duplicates anyway if the different descriptions are provided both for individual product and for the product group. If you need to resolve such kind of duplicates then every LEFT JOIN needs to me made 2 times (for the product and for the group) and then the appropriate description should be taken with COALESCE.
Result

Edit: Example how to avoid the latter kind of duplicates
select 
    product_features.year,
    product_features.product,
    product_features.feature,
    substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) AS product_group,
    COALESCE(text_en.description1, text_en_gen.description1) AS en,
    COALESCE(text_de.description1, text_de_gen.description1) AS de
FROM product_features
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_en
ON text_en.year = product_features.year
AND text_en.feature = product_features.feature
AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_en.product_group)
AND text_en.language = 1
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_en_gen
ON text_en_gen.year = product_features.year
AND text_en_gen.feature = product_features.feature
AND (text_en_gen.product_group IS NULL OR TRIM(text_en_gen.product_group) = '')
AND text_en_gen.language = 1
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_de
ON text_de.year = product_features.year
AND text_de.feature = product_features.feature
AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_de.product_group)
AND text_de.language = 2
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_de_gen
ON text_de_gen.year = product_features.year
AND text_de_gen.feature = product_features.feature
AND (text_de_gen.product_group IS NULL OR TRIM(text_de_gen.product_group) = '')
AND text_de_gen.language = 2


I think my query is relatively fast because of less joins. If the data assumes than the "generic" descriptions are always present then the _gen joins (the 2nd and the 4th) could be changed to INNER joins which improve index usage ability.
Also if product_group is always NULL for the generic description and newer a white-space string then there is no need for the second condition (TRIM(text_de_gen.product_group) = '') and the execution plan will be more effective because we don't need to call the TRIM for every row

I think the whole CTE stuff is really not what you want. I think you want one row per product, so start with that
select
    f.*,
    substring(f.product, 1, 2) as product_group
from product_features f

and then for each product you want to fetch the corresponding description if it exists which can simply be done in a subquery column for english:
    (
        select description1
        from feature_text t
        where f.year = t.year
            and (product_group = t.product_group or t.product_group = ' ' or t.product_group is null)
            and f.feature = t.feature
            and language = 1
    ) as feature_text_en

and for the german:
    (
        select description1
        from feature_text t
        where f.year = t.year
            and (product_group = t.product_group or t.product_group = ' ' or t.product_group is null)
            and f.feature = t.feature
            and language = 2
    ) as feature_text_de

Here is both together on sqlime and produces this result table:



year
product
feature
product_group
feature_text_en
feature_text_de




2024
B12XBE
A1C
B1
B1 hardened steal
B1 gehärteter Stahl


2024
B12XBE
7B0
B1
B1 diamond tip
B1 Diamant Spitze


2024
B12XBE
DUL
B1
10mm for light duty
10mm für leichte Aufgaben


2024
UTB2EF
A1C
UT
UT hardened steal
UT gehärteter Stahl


2024
UTB2EF
7B0
UT
UT diamond tip
UT Diamant Spitze


2024
UTB2EF
DUL
UT
10mm for light duty
10mm für leichte Aufgaben


2024
X9Y8Z7
DUH
X9
13mm for heavy duty
13mm für schwere Aufgaben


2024
X9Y8Z7
7B0
X9
X9 diamond tip
X9 Diamant Spitze



